# What is the difference in "directly assigning the class object to another object of same class" and "using clone() "

Tags: java, clone

I am new to `Java` coding. I have doubts about getting a copy of an object.

I tried to just assign the obj with another object of same `Class`, and it worked. I confirmed it by accessing the items of the class in both objects and they are same. Then what is the use of `clone()` ?

code sample:

```html
class student
{
  int id;
  String name;
}

student s1 = new student();
student s2= new student();
s1.id =10;
s2=s1;
```

so `s2` also has the same copy as that of `s1` - yes? Then what is the need for cloning?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: `class Thingy {String s;}   Thingy t1 = new Thingy();   Thingy t2 = t1;   t2.s = "Hello";    System.out.println(t1.s);`

Comment: I don't see any call to `clone()` in the code you've posted.

Comment: my question is what is the difference in using clone() and the implementation i have shown without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning the object is nothing but a reference pointing to the created object. But clone is exact duplicate of the entire object. 
Try to change value with the new reference , the actual object attributes will get changed but in you clone only newly created object will get changed the actual object remains the same.

Comment: oh i see. that sounds right. thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

The clone() method saves the extra processing task for creating the exact copy of an object. If we perform it by using the new keyword, it will take a lot of processing to be performed that is why we use object cloning.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign one object to another object, it is only referencing to same location . i.e. both objects have same memory location. If you check, both the objects will have same values for the properties.

But, it exposes a problem. Whenever you update the first object, the values of the second object also gets updated.

Example:

```
public class Student implements Cloneable{

int id;
String name;

public Student(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Student s1 = new Student(10, "A");
    Student s2 = s1;                        //simply assigning the s1 object's reference to s2
    Student s3= (Student)s1.clone();        //assigning s1 object's clone to s3

    System.out.printf("Before updation::s1.id->%d, s1.name->%s\n",s1.id, s1.name);
    System.out.printf("Before updation::s2.id->%d, s2.name->%s\n",s2.id, s2.name);
    System.out.printf("Before updation::s3.id->%d, s3.name->%s\n",s3.id, s3.name);

    s1.id = 20;
    s1.name= "Z";

    System.out.printf("After updation::s1.id-%d, s1.name->%s\n",s1.id, s1.name);
    System.out.printf("After updation::s2.id-%d, s2.name->%s\n",s2.id, s2.name);
    System.out.printf("After updation::s3.id-%d, s3.name->%s\n",s3.id, s3.name);
}
}
```

**Output:**
`Before updation::s1.id->10, s1.name->A`
`Before updation::s2.id->10, s2.name->A`
`Before updation::s3.id->10, s3.name->A`
`After updation::s1.id-20, s1.name->Z`
`After updation::s2.id-20, s2.name->Z`
`After updation::s3.id-10, s3.name->A`

Generally clone method of an object, creates a new instance of the same class and copies all the fields to the new instance and returns it. This is nothing but shallow copy. Object class provides a clone method and provides support for the shallow copy. It returns ‘Object’ as type and you need to explicitly cast back to your original object.

So when you change the values of the original object, the cloned object's values remains the same.

Since the Object class has the clone method (protected) you cannot use it in all your classes. The class which you want to be cloned should implement clone method and overwrite it. It should provide its own meaning for copy or to the least it should invoke the super.clone(). Also you have to implement Cloneable marker interface or else you will get CloneNotSupportedException.